# Como faço para mostrar um erro php no jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, aplicação-web

Eu tenho um (.html), um (.php) e o meu jQuery.

No meu jQuery( estou enviando as informações para o (.php) fazer o CRUD e etc.

As transações estão ocorrendo tranquilamente, porém,não estão exibindo mensagens de erro do tipo ("Campo id_pessoa não pode ser em branco).

Como faço isso?

```js
$('#cadastrar').on('click', function(){
 var opcaoCadastrar = $(this).attr("value");
 var nome = $('#nome').val();
 $.post('consulta.php',
 {opcaoCadastrarEnvia:opcaoCadastrar,nomeEnviarCadastrar:nome},function(data){
  
 });
 
});
```

```html
if (isset($_POST['opcaoCadastrarEnvia'])){
    
  $nome = $_POST['nomeEnviarCadastrar'];
  $consulta = "INSERT INTO FUNCIONARIO (FUN_NOME)VALUES(:nome)";
  $resultado->$db_con->prepare($consulta);
  $resultado->BindParam(':nome',$nome,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $resultado->execute();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A muito tempo não trabalho com jquery, mas creio que seja assim:

```
 $('#cadastrar').on('click', function(){
        var opcaoCadastrar = $(this).attr("value");
        var nome = $('#nome').val();
        $.post('consulta.php',
        {opcaoCadastrarEnvia:opcaoCadastrar,nomeEnviarCadastrar:nome},function(data){

        }).fail(function(response) {
          alert('Error: ' + response.responseText);
     });

    });
```

Para versões antigas (pre-1.8) Use `.error` no lugar de `.fail`

Comment: Não funcionou, continua sem mensagens de erro =/

Comment: Vamos por partes. Dentro do bloco post, acrescente console.log(data). O que é exibido no console?

Comment: $('#cadastrar').on('click', function(){
 var opcaoCadastrar = $(this).attr("value");
 var nome = $('#nome').val();
 $.post('consulta.php',
 {opcaoCadastrarEnvia:opcaoCadastrar,nomeEnviarCadastrar:nome},function(data){
  console.log(data);
 });
 
});

Comment: Continua retornando nada.

Comment: Isso significa que nem mesmo o request está sendo feito, você precisa de a) ver os erros que estão no console e b) acesse o seu script php diretamente e veja o erro que aparece

Comment: Meu script estava no meu index(funcionando), mas como todas as minhas outras transações estavam no meu (.jQuery), resolvi colocar lá também, é a única que não está funcionando. Tenho certeza que são pelos campos not null no meu banco, porém, eu queria que estes erros fossem retornados igual eram no meu index.

Comment: Se eu colocar um try/catch no meu php, será que resolveria o problema?

Comment: Podemos tentar :)